# Exploding the last portion of a url everytime

Tags: php

On my website I have some urls that look like this.

```
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-one-81347.html our post name number one 
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-two-81348.html our post name number two
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-three-81349.html our post name number three
```

And I am needing to get the part right befor the `.html` which contains a random number, under no stance will this number ever be the same.

Currently, I am storing these urls inside of a `.txt` file which has the title of the post also included, and exploding via this method below.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://example.com/urls/delete.txt'));
foreach ($array  as $item) {
    $removed = "copyright";
    $nothing = "";
    $url = explode(" ", $item);
    $data = $url[0];
    $explode = explode(".html", $data);
    // other functions
    $primary =  $explode[0];
    print $primary; 
    print '<br>';
}
```

The above code is currently returning this.

```
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-one-81347
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-two-81348
http://example.com/our-post-name-here-number-three-81349
```

When I only want it to return this `81347` `81348` `81349`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use regex.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://example.com/urls/delete.txt'));
foreach ($array  as $item)
{
    $regex = "/.*-([\d]+)\.html.*$/";
    preg_match ( $regex , $item , $matches );
    $primary =  $matches[1];

    print $primary; 
    print '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it to this function:

```
function url_post_id($url) {
    $i = strripos($url, "-");
    $j = stripos($url, ".", $i);
    return substr($url, $i+1, $j-$i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the same format is guaranteed, you can split one more time by `-`, and get the last element with [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php):

```
$pieces = explode("-", $primary);
$number = array_pop($pieces); 
print $number;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/g5IQB)